# Rollback en Mongoose, Transacciones

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transacciones, nosql

Tengo una API utilizando Mongoose y desde ella actualizo la información de un usuario. Pero el problema es que tengo que actualizar dos colecciones en donde se guarda también información del usuario, ¿hay alguna manera que me permita realizar por ejemplo una transacción?

Es decir, que si al actualizar la segunda colección existe algún error me realice una especie de rollback sobre la actualización del usuario y de la primera colección. Algo como esto:

```
Try{
  UpdateUser()
  UpdateUserColec1()
  UpdateuserColec2()
}
Catch{
  Rollback();
}
```

Investigué acerca de transacciones en mondogoDB pero me dice que no están habilitadas.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MongoDB y Mongoose utilizas?